# Why result of function in loop isn't correct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I try to put some data from XML into my model object. (lib for XML - xml.etree.cElementTree)
I've created function "split_path" and I'm trying use it in loop.

```
#My function:
def split_path(diction):
    separated_path = output['path'].replace('$', '').split('/')
    for k in separated_path:
        path_dict = {'key':separated_path[0], 'table':separated_path[1], 'attribute':separated_path[2]}
    return path_dict
```

As a result in jupiter notebook I got:

```
{'path': '$_source1/LDS_PERSONALDATEN_F/LDS_HID_PERSONEN_NR'}
{'key': '_target2', 'table': 'IDS_S_NAT_PERSON', 'attribute': 'IDS_H_NAT_PERSON_HID'}
{'path': '$_source698/LDS_PER/LDS_ONEN_NR'}
{'key': '_target2', 'table': 'IDS_S_NAT_PERSON', 'attribute': 'IDS_H_NAT_PERSON_HID'}
```

so 1st and 3rd line show that my argument is changing. I don't know why 2nd and 4th are the same...

Part of code which return above result:

```
# Code for checking result:
while mkey == 'input':
    print(m.attrib)
    print(split_path(m.attrib))
    break
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a read through [ask] for tips on writing a good question. As it's currently written, it's difficult to debug your code. Specifically, we don't know what `output` is. Also, you've shown us a loop, but how is it being used? What is `m.attrib`? Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces your issue. Tom's answer below makes some good points: 1) you're not using the `diction` parameter and 2) you're overwriting `path_dict` on each iteration in the for-loop. But other than that, it's hard to guess what is wanted... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def split_path(diction):
    separated_path = diction['path'].replace('$', '').split('/')
    for k in separated_path:
        path_dict = {'key':separated_path[0], 'table':separated_path[1], 'attribute':separated_path[2]}
    return path_dict
```

You used the wrong variable name - output instead of diction

By the way when you loop through `separated_path` you override `path_dict`. So your result would be only the result of the last iteration. Is that really what you want?